# Determining for which complex numbers $z, w$ it is true that $\sqrt{z^2} = z$ and $\sqrt{w^2} = -w$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Preinfo:** Let $z, \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{Arg}(z)$ denote the principal argument of $z$ with branch cut being at $-\pi$. Then either $\sqrt{z^2} = z$ or $\sqrt{z^2} = -z$. To determine when $\sqrt{z^2} = z$ we can use the polar form of $z$ to see that $\sqrt{|z|^2\exp(i\mathrm{Arg}(z^2))} = |z|\exp\left(i\frac{\mathrm{Arg}(z^2)}{2}\right) = |z|\exp(i\mathrm{Arg}(z))$ exactly when $\mathrm{Arg}(z) = \frac{\mathrm{Arg}(z^2)}{2}$. Since $\frac{\mathrm{Arg}(z^2)}{2} \in (-\pi, \pi]$ it follows that $\mathrm{Arg}(z) \in \left(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Then we would know immediately that for $w \in \mathbb{C}$ we need to have that $\mathrm{Arg}(w) \in \left(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]^c$, if we want that $\sqrt{w^2} = -w$.

**Question:** But I'm interested in knowing how you could infer the argument requirement for $w$ without using the prior knowledge of the argument of $z$ such that $\sqrt{z^2} = -z$. Then similary we know that $\frac{\mathrm{Arg}(w^2)}{2} = -\mathrm{Arg}(w)$ so that in a sense $\mathrm{Arg}(w) \in \left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. However, this isn't really the range of values we want, as we need $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)\cup \left(-\pi,\frac{-\pi}{2}\right]$. But how to deduce this algebraically without using information regarding $\sqrt{z^2} = z$?

Answer (score 1):

The *principal* square root function, applied to complex numbers has as its range the complex numbers $z$ such that the Real component of $z$ is non-negative.

Note that this makes the customary non-negative square root of a Real number to be a special case of the (therefore consistent) *principal* square root of complex numbers.

Anyway, it is therefore immediate that the principal square root of $(w^2)$ is not $w$ whenever $w$ does not have a non-negative real component.

---

Note that the inference in the above paragraph critically requires knowledge of the range of the principal square root function applied to complex numbers.  That is, if you did not care about consistency between square roots on the Real number line and square roots in the complex plane, you could *reverse* the convention around the principal square root function in the complex plane.

Then, you would have that the range of the principal square root function, in the complex plane is all complex numbers with a non-positive real component.